# Notepad++: Opening a Workspace/Project from commandline?

Tags: notepad++

Since v5.9.4, npp supports *projects* in a *workspace* (Menu View/Project/Project-Panel x). I'd like to open this prepared workspace/project directly from commandline (on different PCs).

How to handle a npp workspace/project from the commandline?

Answer (score 1):

#### Sessions:

You can open a session file using the flag [`-openSession`](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches), e.g.:

```
C:\npp.6.7.8.2.bin>notepad++ -openSession your_file_name
```

For UI association (double-clicking), you can make Notepad++ recognize sessions via 'Settings' → 'Preferences' → 'MISC' → ['Session file ext'](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sessions_And_Projects#Session_files):

[image]

#### Workspaces:

Workspace is a bit *odd*. It seems like you can have only one Workspace open at any one time, and there doesn't seem to be any way to open a save Workspace directly. (You'd have to <kbd>Right-Click</kbd><kbd>Open Workspace</kbd>.)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a directory as workspace using the following command

```
notepad++ -openFoldersAsWorkspace .
```

This will open the current directory as workspace.. Replace `.` with the path to another directory if you want.